# undefined method `current_page' for #<Array:0x007fd5ef6dd158> kaminari

Tags: methods, pagination, undefined, kaminari, current-page

Rails 3.2.8 im using kaminari to do pagination, but i keep getting error:
undefined method `current_page' for #

in `posts_controller.rb`

```
def index
  @posts = Post.order(:created_at).page(params[:page])
end
```

in `views/posts/index.html.erb`

```
<%= paginate @posts %>
```

what could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

try to change the code to

```
@posts = Post.order(:created_at)

Kaminari.paginate_array(@posts).page(params[:page]).per(10)
```

Or

```
@posts = Post.order(:created_at).page(params[:page]).per(10)
Kaminari.paginate_array(@posts).page(params[:page]).per(10)
```

And you can write any number in place of 10 => .per(10)
Let the view code remain same.

will_paginate default comes with pagination for `ActiveRecord::Relation` but for an Array we need to use this particular method.

Comment: This doesn't explain why the official method of using the gem doesn't work.